# How to use OOP efficiently? Can I get some reference

Tags: oop

I dont know if this question is suitable here but I recently attended interview in which I answered all of the typical OOP FAQ. But at the end interviewer told me that I know OOP concepts but dont know how to apply them in real application. So I just want to know if there is any good book available for me to understand and apply OOP concepts in real application example. I have searched everywhere and I finally came here to ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think your interviewer knows what he/she is talking about. If you know OOP concepts, then it's impossible not to know how to apply them in an application. Having said this, still voting to close. Too broad a question with no specific right or wrong answer.

Comment: Start reading design patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some good books that helped me:

- Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software
- Object Design - Roles, Responsibilities, and Collaborations - Rebecca Wirfs-Brock
- Analysis Patterns Reusable Object Models
- AntiPatterns, Refactoring Software, Architectures, and Projects in Crisis
- Clean Code - A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship
- Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design

I would also say that it's best to read these in conjunction with doing a real project. If you don't have a real project, actually code the ones in the books as they go along. It may seem unnecessary, but your fingers learning is just as important as your head learning! That's "practical knowledge"; sitting down to code and not hesitating b/c your hands know what to do.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the books